# How to change android gradle ndk -j (--jobs) flag value for clean task?

Tags: android, gradle, ndk-build

I use `-j` flag to speed up ndk compile time like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            arguments "-j8"
        }
    }
}
```

Building works fine, but clean produces this error:

```
rm: fts_read: No such file or directory
```

This is documented in Google's ndk-build docs, and the reason for this is parallel execution (`-j` flag) on Mac, so I need to either remove this flag or change it to `-j1` for clean task. How can I do this?

Comment: FYI, that bug is fixed in NDK r18: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
def getProcessesCountArg() {
    def procCount = Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors()

    Gradle gradle = getGradle()
    def isClean = gradle.getStartParameter().getTaskNames().find { it ==~ /.*clean.*/ }
    if (isClean) {
        procCount = 1
    }

    return "-j" + procCount
}
```

Wish there was a better way.

Comment: No longer necessary. It's fixed in NDK r18: https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/198